Different Job title and Responsibilities
I have joined company X as an Software Developer Engineer.
I was trained in full stack development, worked on a few front-end development tasks for a couple of months. I was later moved to the automation testing team for the same application.
In their system, my job title says I'm a "developer", and even in the experience letter I got from that company, my role is mentioned as a developer.
So, how should I put this all into my resume? I'm thinking of listing both development and testing works under the same job title.

Does this answer your question? Is it ethical to put a job title representing the work I actually performed instead of my given title on a resume?

You list your job title as whatever your employer decides to call you.  Under that you describe what your actual responsibilities were.

Wouldn't listing Dev and testing responsibilities under Dev create problems with resume parsers?

@Ganesh why would it? If it's a dumb parser perhaps

@Ganesh another way to put Dan's answer: usually job titles vary a lot between companies. "Senior Wizard" may not be the same role/responsibilities as a Senior Wizard on another company. However, you can't make up your title. Thus, you respect the title given, but under that briefly describe your responsibilities (which tell way more than a title).

@DarkCygnus Thanks. I just listed everything i did under the given job title

Titles don't matter in the software engineer world.  What matters most is your skills and experience.
Having a strong skills section, and a strong write up of your responsibilities will trump whatever silly title you were given.  In fact you could have something like this:

June 2020-Present Company X, Developer

Performed as a Full Stack Software Engineer by doing .....
Did front end develop using .....
Modified the xxx DB .....
Created web services using .....


So I would be accurate with the job title, but you can easily overcome this by the rest of your resume.
An example of this is when works as a contractor.  You are typically given a not very meaningful title, something like "developer" despite your pay rate being more than your manager's.  One job I contracted at had me conducting the interviews, they did not trust their full time employees to do so.
In my almost 30 years experience I've never had a question come up about title, just my skills and abilities.  This despite having some silly titles like "Programmer/Analyst" despite doing the work of a full stack developer.

NO, this is incorrect. Titles matter when one CHANGES jobs. You could accept a job as a junior engineer, learn all the responsibilities of the junior and senior roles. If there's never a promotion, and you're looking for a senior role, an unwitting resume screener may flag a resume if the hiring manager says they only want applicants who have actively been in a senior role already -- despite whatever experience the resume may convey.
